# Datastage server - OS Upgradation

Tags: service, operating-system, migration, datastage, checklistbox

I am using DS 11.7  installed on OS Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard, We need to upgrade the OS to Windows Server 2016 Standard Edition.

Can Anyone help me with Steps to be followed for this migration.

I Have prepared general checklist like starting and stopping DS services, Disabling Scheduled jobs

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, I would install the DataStage Server on a linux system, but that's not answering the question.
- I highly recommend to write everything to your own custom checklist. Every command you will type, every "knob you will press", every email you might want to send. The official IBM documentation will mention stuff that you might not need or refer to pages that refer to pages that refer to stuff you don't need or which is confusing. Your own list will end up being shorter.
- Therefore, I also highly recommend to talk through your list together with a good teammate that has the spirit and knowledge to assist you. They should also be your wingman when the actual work is happening.
- As always: Make a backup of the old system. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=restoring-backing-up-components
- Backed up everything? Now dump crap. Now is a good opportunity. Loose weight before moving eveything to the new home.
- Setup a new machine with your new OS
- Install the newest version of IBM Infosphere Information Server DataStage on your new machine.
- To perform a migration, the steps should be pretty much the same as in migrating from a lower DataStage Version to the current version (not doing an inplace upgrade).

  - Refer to this documentation: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=checklists-checklist-migration-from-version-1171

Comment: Hi Justus Kenklies, Thank you for your sharing your inputs. We are in a plan to upgrade only OS , DS version will remain same. Do I need to take backup of metadata, parameter ,File / folders  and database connection

Comment: Are you asking me if you should have a backup?

Comment: Yes Justus, if we are not upgrading the DS version , we need to just upgrade the OS

Comment: Okay please don't get me wrong, this is a very basic answer, unrelated to DataStage. Although an inplace upgrade of the OS shouldn't necessarily fail, I would always prefer to have and recommend to do a backup. It might seem the easiest and cheapest way to just approach and hope it won't fail, but compared to the risk of a failure, the effort to make a backup should be worth it.